# How do I stack columns a dataframe while maintaining their order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation, stack

I have been through many articles and stackoverflow questions but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'Price': [10, 12, 14, 16]})
test
    ID  Price
0   5   10
1   6   12
2   7   14
3   8   16
```

I would like to take all the values in price and add it to the 'ID' column. I don't need the price column anymore. (Please ignore the irrationality of this request it's just an example) In my actual case I have many more columns to all be added into column 1. (they are all in the same dtype)

`df.stack()` yields this result:

```
0  ID        5
   Price    10
1  ID        6
   Price    12
2  ID        7
   Price    14
3  ID        8
   Price    16
```

Ideal result:

```
    ID
0   5
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   10
5   12
6   14
7   16
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `test.unstack().to_frame(name='ID').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Or: `out = pd.DataFrame({'ID': test.values.ravel('F')})`